# Mongodump fails with "a direct connection cant be made if multiple hosts are specified"

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I have a dev & staging database which i connect to regularly (using `mongoose.connect(<uri>)`).

I would like to mongodump them. Im using the following syntax:

```
mongodump --uri=<uri>
```

This works fine for dev and I was able to dump the dev database using this command.  The staging database however produces the following error:

**Failed: can't create session: error configuring the connector: a direct connection cannot be made if multiple hosts are specified**

Does anyone know or have any insight on what the issue could be? I haven't found any docs or posts about this error.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `mongoose` and `mongodump`, but the error says that your staging uri contains `directConnection=true` and multiple host names (in contrast to the dev) and this is restricted since the whole idea of directConnection=true to use only a single host name which in turns means that if you specify more than one host name it will be an ambiguous situation. You should change the uri

Comment: @dododo im not sure i follow. I thought the uri points directly to a host, where would 'multiple host names' come into play here? How can i modify the uri?

Comment: your uri can contain multiply hosts like: `mongodb://localhost:27017,localhost27018..`. The solution is to leave only single host name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Historically, when given a URI with one host in it (or otherwise a single host to connect to), some MongoDB drivers performed a *direct connection* to that host only and some drivers inspected the type of the server and, if it was a replica set node, *connected to replica set* (which may have caused none of the queries or commands to be sent to the host which was originally given in the URI).

In the MongoDB 4.4-compatible drivers the behavior was unified, and `directConnection` URI option added to force either behavior (true to connect to the specified host, false to perform discovery; if not set, the driver would do whatever it did historically).

When direct connection is used, you can only specify one host. Your URI contains or resolves to more than one.

For the gritty details, see https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/pull/739.

Comment: This is great info and seems accurate based on the error, however my uri is a standard connection string - ```mongodb://[username:password@]host1``` and it doesn't specify multiple hosts

Comment: I suppose it's possible it resolves to more than one. Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: For what exactly?

Comment: For the scenario of the URI resolving to multiple hosts as you mentioned.

Comment: The operation you are attempting to perform doesn't make sense. Don't do it.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Is there no way to use mongodump in the environment i'm describing?

Comment: You cannot get a direct connection to multiple hosts. Either remove the URI option or specify which one host to connect to.